# GetLogicalDrives() for loop

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am new to the win32 api and need help trying to understand how the GetLogicalDrives() function works. I am trying to populate a cbs_dropdownlist with all the available drives that are not in use. here is what I have so far. I would appreciate any help.

```
void FillListBox(HWND hWndDropMenu)
{
 DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
 for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
 {
    SendMessage(hWndDropMenu, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)drives);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `GetLogicalDrives` returns a *bitmask* of the logical drives available. Here is how you would do it:

```
 DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
 for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
 {
    if( !( drives & ( 1 << i ) ) )
    {
       TCHAR driveName[] = { TEXT('A') + i, TEXT(':'), TEXT('\\'), TEXT('\0') };
       SendMessage(hWndDropMenu, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)driveName);
    }
 }
```

The code checks whether the *i-th* bit in the *bitmask* is *not* set to `1` or `true`.

Comment: From what I understand, `GetLogicalDrives()` returns a bitmask which contains a zero if a drive is available. I want to populate a dropdownlist with only the letters not in use. Does `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` return all drives even if they are in use?

Comment: @arynhard: Sorry, I missed that you wanted the opposite of the logical drives. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you! You have been very helpful.

Comment: Slight problem. I am getting a bunch of Chinese characters in  my list.

Comment: @arynhard: I would believe you are using _Unicode_ instead of _MultiByte_ characters, change `CHAR` for `WCHAR` and every occurrence of `'?'` for `L'?'`. Damned those _Windows_ macros that fail to catch the simplest of mistakes...

Comment: Could also be my inexperience :) I still have to learn when and how to use either type. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @arynhard: No, its actually a _WinAPI_ design issue for using macros, which don't have means to check the correct types are been used. However, while its an awful design choice in _C++_, _C_ provides no other alternatives...

Comment: @Skurmedel: +1 anyway, your answer provides so much detail.

Comment: I agree. :) Thanks for the depth of info

Comment: Better yet, if you want to support both Unicode and MBCS, use the macros intended for that purpose. (Also, I'd declare `drives` as a `const`, but that's a stylistic thing. My style in C++ is to use `const` whenever absolutely possible.)

Answer (score 4):

`GetLogicalDrives` returns a bitmask and to inspect it you need to use bitwise operators. To see if drive A is in use:

```
GetLogicalDrives() & 1 == 1
```

If drive A is unavailable, `GetLogicalDrives() & 1` would yield `0` and the condition would fail.

To check the next drive you'll need to use the next multiple of 2, `GetLogicalDrives() & 2`, `GetLogicalDrives() & 4` and so on.

You could use `GetLogicalDriveStrings` but this returns the inverse of what you want, all the used logical drives.

I would build a table instead, and index into that:

```
const char *drive_names[] = 
{
    "A:",
    "B:",
    ...
    "Z:"
};
```

Then your loop could be:

```
DWORD drives_bitmask = GetLogicalDrives();

for (DWORD i < 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    // Shift 1 to a multiple of 2. 1 << 0 = 1 (0000 0001), 1 << 1 = 2 etc.
    DWORD mask_index = 1 << i;
    if (drives_bitmask & i == 0)
    {
        // Drive unavailable, add it to list.
        const char *name = drive_names[i];
        // ... do GUI work.
    }
}
```